# How to generate random number which is same for two set of elements in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, saxon

Input:

```
<paragraph>
      <bq>34152</bq>
      <eq>52325/eq>
      <private type="DOB">SP1</private>
      <bq>12431</bq>
      <abc>EX</abc>
      <eq>31333</eq>
</paragraph>
```

Expected Output:

```
<paragraph>
          <bq>55124</bq>
          <eq>55124</eq>
          <private type="DOB">SP1</private>
          <bq>66565</bq>
          <abc>EX</abc>
          <eq>66565</eq>
</paragraph>
```

How to use apply-templates to generate same random number for every bq and eq set?

Comment: Which version of Saxon do you use? XSLT 3 with PE or EE 9.8 or later and HE 10 or later has `random-number-generator` as an XPath function.

Comment: GIven that you're using Saxon and therefore have fn:random-number-generator() available, what part of the problem are you having trouble with?

Comment: Use [grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info) to create a group for each pair of `bq` and `eq`. Generate a random number and place it into a variable. Use the variable to populate both  `bq` and `eq` of the current group. --- Note that there is no native way to generate a random number in XSLT 2.0. If you're using Saxon, you can probably move up to XSLT 3.0. Otherwise you will have to find some other method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XSLT 3 (e.g. with `random-number-generator`) it would boil down to

```
  <xsl:accumulator name="rng" as="map(*)" initial-value="random-number-generator(current-dateTime())">
    <xsl:accumulator-rule match="paragraph/bq" select="$value?next()"/>
  </xsl:accumulator>
  
  <xsl:template match="paragraph/bq | paragraph/eq" expand-text="yes">
    <xsl:copy>{round(accumulator-before('rng')?number * 100000)}</xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy" use-accumulators="rng"/>
```

That requires Saxon HE 10 or later or Saxon PE/EE 9.8 or later or Saxon-JS 2.